# Replace directory path Drupal 6.20

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I try to guard a file, which I save from a form, in a path I specify. I use file_directory_path that returns the path to default, what do i do  to change the path or to modify it to personalize it?

Code that this done but it does not function

```
 $filepath='/sites/ficheros_profesores';
//   str_replace(file_directory_path(),'',$filepath); 
     $file = file_save_upload('test',null,file_directory_path());
     file_set_status($file, FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I properly understood, you are trying to save the uploaded file in a folder which is inside the default 'files' directory, isn't it?

Instead str_replace, you could concatenate the strings with '.'. Simply:

```
$file = file_save_upload('test',null,file_directory_path().'/sites/ficheros_profesores');
```

You should then ensure that the '/sites/ficheros_profesores/' exists and that the 'www-data' user (asuming linux) has the proper permissions.

Hope it helps.